# Android resource linking failed AAPT: error: failed writing to

Tags: java, android, aapt, android-studio-4.1

`AAPT`: error: failed writing to '

> C:\Users
> DEV\Desktop\Gamers\app\build\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list\debug\R.txt
> ':The data is invalid. (13).

I have tried to clean and rebuild the project. I have also tried deleting the folder but it has failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be some windows issue. Try to move the project to `C:\proj_name`, so there will be no `whitespaces` in the project path. And if that does`t help - run Android Studio as Administrator.

Comment: I have tried but still it's showing the error

Comment: try running the android studio as administrator

Comment: Thanks it worked