# AAPT: error: failed writing to 'path_to_android_project\app\build\intermediates\runtime_symbol_list\devDebug\R.txt': The data is invalid. (13)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, antivirus

Even though I noticed this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600174/android-resource-linking-failed-aapt-error-failed-writing-to), the solution provided is not what worked for me, and that question is now closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incredible as it sounds, the solution was to disable my antivirus (I was using Avast Free). Even though there is no clue in the error indicating that is the problem, building worked perfectly after disabling the shields, with no other changes in the project.